# How to import json to a ionic timeline project

Tags: json, ionic-framework

```
export class HomePage {
  items = [
    {
      title: 'Courgette daikon',
      content: 'Parsley amaranth tigernut silver beet maize fennel spinach. Ricebean black-eyed pea maize scallion green bean spinach cabbage jícama bell pepper carrot onion corn plantain garbanzo. Sierra leone bologi komatsuna celery peanut swiss chard silver beet squash dandelion maize chicory burdock tatsoi dulse radish wakame beetroot.',
      icon: 'calendar',
      time: {subtitle: '4/16/2013', title: '21:30'}
    },
    {
      title: 'Courgette daikon',
      content: 'Parsley amaranth tigernut silver beet maize fennel spinach. Ricebean black-eyed pea maize scallion green bean spinach cabbage jícama bell pepper carrot onion corn plantain garbanzo. Sierra leone bologi komatsuna celery peanut swiss chard silver beet squash dandelion maize chicory burdock tatsoi dulse radish wakame beetroot.',
      icon: 'calendar',
      time: {subtitle: 'January', title: '29'}
    },
    {
      title: 'Courgette daikon',
      content: 'Parsley amaranth tigernut silver beet maize fennel spinach. Ricebean black-eyed pea maize scallion green bean spinach cabbage jícama bell pepper carrot onion corn plantain garbanzo. Sierra leone bologi komatsuna celery peanut swiss chard silver beet squash dandelion maize chicory burdock tatsoi dulse radish wakame beetroot.',
      icon: 'calendar',
      time: {title: 'Short Text'}
    }
  ]
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

Insted of the manually entered json, i would like to import this from a json file that is

> {"items":[{"agendaid":"1","title":"Avreise Medina","content":"Avreise
>   til Medina er klokken 18:30, det er oppm\u00f8te p\u00e5 flyplassen 3
>   timer f\u00f8r avreise. Alle m\u00e5 selv komme tidsnok til \u00e5
>   f\u00e5 sitte sammen andre i familien. Det er kun lov til \u00e5 ha
>   med seg 30 kg baggasje og 7 kg
>   h\u00e5ndbaggasje","icon":"plane","TimeTitle":"21.12.2017","TimeSubtitle":"18:30","ExecuteTime":"2017-12-21
>   18:30:00"},{"agendaid":"2","title":"test","content":"test","icon":"test","TimeTitle":"test","TimeSubtitle":"test","ExecuteTime":"2017-11-22
>   17:26:23"}]}

Im trying to read it in ionic 3 with this code

```
    url: string = 'http://backend.mishkaat.no/app/agenda.php';
        items: any = [];

        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private http: Http ) {}

        ionViewDidEnter() {
            this.http.get( this.url )
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
              // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
              // and save the data for later reference
              this.items = data;
            });
        }
```

But getting this error:

```
    Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
        at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:7695:19)
        at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:43776:57)
        at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12451:19)
        at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13951:20)
        at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13894:16)
        at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14766:76)
        at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14707:13)
        at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/AgendaPage.ngfactory.js:99:5)
        at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14692:21)
        at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13861:14)
```

when displaying it in the html file

```
    <timeline endIcon="call">
        <timeline-item *ngFor="let item of items">
          <timeline-time [time]="item.time"></timeline-time>
          <ion-icon [name]="item.icon"></ion-icon>
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-header>
              {{item.title}}
            </ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-content>
              {{item.content}}
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
        </timeline-item>
    </timeline>
```

Any help ?

Comment: Please check this code `this.items = data.items;`

Comment: Thank you! It solved it!

Comment: New qustion has arrived.

Answer (score 0):

I now have the original json file that is in the question, but why arent im able to read the nested json with this script ?

```
@Component({
  selector:'timeline-time',
  template: '<span>{{time.subtitle}}</span> <span>{{time.title}}</span>'
})
export class TimelineTimeComponent{
  @Input('time') time = {};
  constructor(){

  }
}
```

Comment: you must ask your question in new page not in answer part.